# CloseHandle after process does not exist

Tags: c++

I have made a quick example.

I just want to know if i need to close the handle before i re attach it to the new process?

```
DWORD g_dwPid = 0;
HANDLE g_hProcess;
int _tWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    while (TRUE) {

        DWORD dwPid = GetProcessIdByName(L"explorer.exe");
        if (dwPid && dwPid != g_dwPid) {
            g_dwPid = dwPid;

            g_hProcess = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, g_dwPid);
        }
        else
            CloseHandle(g_hProcess);

        Sleep(500);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should always close the handle returned by `OpenProcess` when you are done with it.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess):

> When you are finished with the handle, be sure to close it using the `CloseHandle` function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to close the handle when you are done using it:

```c
DWORD g_dwPid = 0;
HANDLE g_hProcess = NULL;

int _tWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    while (TRUE) {

        DWORD dwPid = GetProcessIdByName(L"explorer.exe");
        if (dwPid) {
            if (dwPid != g_dwPid) {
                g_dwPid = dwPid;
                if (g_hProcess) CloseHandle(g_hProcess); // <-- ADD THIS!
                g_hProcess = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, g_dwPid);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (g_hProcess) {
                CloseHandle(g_hProcess); // <-- ADD THIS!
                g_hProcess = NULL;
            }
        }

        Sleep(500);
    }

    if (g_hProcess)
        CloseHandle(g_hProcess); // <-- ADD THIS!

    return 0;
}
```

Also note that once you do successfully open the process, as long as you keep the handle open, the process will not be able to go away completely, so your search is likely to keep finding it.

Comment: What happens if my program is forced closed in task manager? Then the handle is never closed? is that bad?

Comment: @werico4026 the handle will be closed automatically when your process exits (same as any other kernel handle it has open)